# GitLab Code Quality job throws 'dotnet not found'

Tags: c#, .net-core, gitlab-ci, code-analysis

I'm trying to perform Code Quality test using GitLab CQ tool applying to my .NET 7 project. I'm a quite new it this, so, firstly I added default trigger to my `.gitlab-ci.yml` for getting this job running

```
include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml
```

and got the error

> /bin/sh: eval: line 140: dotnet: not found

[image]

After that, I've tried to change the image, used by CQ tool, because I think the error occurs as CQ image has not `dotnet` installed

```
code_quality:
  variables:
    CODE_QUALITY_IMAGE: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0"
```

but this didn't solve the problem - I'm still getting the same error. I googled a lot and didn't find any helpful highlights.

So, what is the correct configuration of `.gitlab-ci.yml` for .NET projects with Code Quality enabled?

Answer (score -1):

As you report that the GitLab runner is unable to find the .NET command-line tool "dotnet", then you may need to install the .NET SDK first (on the machine that's running the GitLab runner.).

You can download and install the .NET SDK from Microsoft's website: [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download).

Then, try running your GitLab CI pipeline again to see if the error has been resolved.

Comment: this did not help

Comment: but when I added `image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` to `code_quality` section, the error changed to `docker: command not found`. so, it seems the cause definitely in image used

Comment: this err message says that GitLab runner cannot find the docker command.  Now you need to have docker installed on your GitLab runner machine. Try using an image that includes docker binaries in your .gitlab-ci.yml file, something like docker:latest or gitlab/dind.